# Change method name of a library

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, class-method

I am using a libary but some method names just suck. Is there a way to safely change those method names without touching the source of the lib?

Comment: No, you can't do that

Comment: Read about patterns. Some like proxy was invited against Your requirement

Answer (score 1):

you can have a header like this

```
inline int NiceName(){return HorribleName();}
```

Doesnt work for class methods though, there you might have to resort to - oh the horror - macros

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to change method name of a class, you can. Simply subclass the original class and add a new method with a pretty name that perfectly forwards it's parameters to the method with an ugly name you would like to change.

```
struct B
{
    // for example
    int UglyName(std::string str, int i)
    { std::cout << str << " " << i << std::endl; return i + 1; }
};

struct C : B
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    auto PrettyName(Args&& ...args)
    { return UglyName(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    std::cout << "return value: " << c.PrettyName("Test Message: ", 23) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

since the method name is ABI level detail, there wont be one answer for every machine... different ABI's use different name mangling schemes and param encoding schemes etc... if you narrow it down to at least an OS, there might be a tool that you can use to rename some methods (binutils or something).. but you will also have to modify headers to use the new name or else the compiler will choke...

Comment: basically it wouldn't ever be worth your effort